# Using jMeter to read values from DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: oracle, jmeter, dbms-output

what would be the easiest/most efficient way to read the values, that have been put in the buffer already?

I have something like this:

```
Dbms_Output.Put_Line('a -> 3');
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(a);
```

And I want to know if I can put anything in my JDBC Sampler, which can read the value of "a" and return it as a response, so I can use it as a parameter in my next request?

I was thinking about Dbms_Output.Get_Line(s), but not sure what should be the syntax and if this will solve my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71776942/1509264

Comment: The primary purpose of `DBMS_OUTPUT` is for debugging. It's is not intended to be used to return data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can execute SQL [statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) like select or update and call [stored procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_programs.htm) and only one statement at a time.

Theoretically you can create a stored procedure like it's described in
[How to Fetch Oracle DBMS_OUTPUT from JDBC](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-fetch-oracle-dbms_output-from-jdbc/) article but I'm not sure whether it's something you're looking for

More information:

- [Difference Between SQL and PLSQL](https://www.interviewbit.com/blog/difference-between-sql-and-plsql/)
- [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)
- [Samples of PL/SQL in JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/samapp2.htm)